# StackExchange login with Kindle Fire HD

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

When I login onto StackExchange network with my Kindle Fire HD (Silk browser) I see the login form like this:
[image]

is really not simple to put right my credential data.

Sometimes the login phase fails, and I have to put my data again. I can't reproduce it, but sometimes it happens...I check cookie's options and they are enabled.

Comment: The Kindle Fire uses Amazon Silk, which is [not an officially supported web browser](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) - there are bound to be some issues when browsing the site with that browser.